# Google map javascript on marker setPosition() sometimes marker disappears and reappears on any mouse event on map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

marker setPosition() method sometimes marker disappears and reappears on any mouse event on map specially scroll event

Answer (score 0):

I found answer to this use map.panBY(0,0) after re-centering the map on setPosition()